# Getting QGIS working with Arcgis feature server - crs issue?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-server

I am having difficulty getting the feature service below to line up properly with other layers.  It renders fine by itself.  How do I determine what crs this service is using?

I am adding this layer with the ArcGIS REST API Connector plugin.

http://services2.arcgis.com/8krRUWgifzA4cgL3/ArcGIS/rest/services/Damage1995Blowdown/FeatureServer/0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you view the link in a browser you'll see in the 'Extent' section the spatial reference is 102100.

You can find see there is some information at this link

http://spatialreference.org/ref/sr-org/6928/

It is basically an ESRI web mercator projection similar to EPSG:3857 which is used in most web map applications (i.e. Google, OSM)

Comment: Bingo! That worked.  I was able to get from 102100 to sr-org:6928, but the last step of getting to epsg:3857 is still a mystery to me.  Anyway, thank you.